# Redmine 4.1 Exporting PDF's images missing

Tags: redmine

Posted on the Redmine forum, but after a few days didn't get a response. I thought someone here might know.

I am trying to export PDF's with images. I have tried using the copy/paste and upload when creating an issue and specifying the file name; all seem to fail exporting the picture. Tried different formats jpg and png, with same results. I have read several forum postings from several years ago, when rmagick would be installed to help solve the issue. From Redmine install page I read that the rmagick is not necessary for 4.1.0.

I am really new to running the redmine world. Running redmine on a Windows box.

How can I allow the images to be exported to PDF for an issue?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                4.1.0.stable
  Ruby version                   2.6.5-p114 (2019-10-01) [x64-mingw32]
  Rails version                  5.2.4.1
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
SCM:
  Git                            1.9.4
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_issue_templates        1.0.1
```

Comment: Are your images attachments, or they are inline?

Comment: I have tried copy/paste the images into the post. The image gets attached automatically and the markup is entered, example: ![](clipboard-202004070948-qbn7l.png).

Comment: I also have tried to attach first and then specified in the post as: ![](android.png)

Comment: I beleive that imagemagick is required for that to work... The one 4.1.0 Redmine that I have lists: ImageMagick PDF support available (optional), among other stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Redmine 4.1 introudced new way and new checkmark in order to have Images visible in PDF

Notice the ImageMagick optional requirement:
[image]

If you check in Redmine log, it would probably dump this message:

```
Imagemagick's convert binary is not available...
```

On the underlying Linux system, **Ghostscript** is also required for above to work.

Comment: The ImageMagick PDF support shows a '!', not a checkmark. I have tried following the instructions here: https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows. Unfortunately it still shows that its still not installed. Maybe the documentation is not up to date on this (last updated 2017).

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I followed the tutorial here (https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/install-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7-8-10-imagemagick-6-9-4-q16-hdri-5492c3fef202). It suggest not to install 7.x.x versions. After I walked through their install process the "ImageMagick convert available" was checked, while the "PDF support" was left with '!'. I was then successfully able to export documents with images being shown

Comment: Yup, I didn't have enough time to pinpoint where exactly is that used in the code, but I stumbled upon some lines, indicating that's required for images in PDF's.